# Is it possible to run an application in Windows Phone in background?

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to run an application in Windows Phone in background?

I want to port a chat application from Android to Windows Phone, that requires to have a persistent Internet connection, so user doesn't need to keep that application opened. When application received a message - need to show a notification.

On Android the connection logic was located in `Service`, but I didn't find analogues for Windows Phone.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows phone 8: how to check if there are new messages on the database (server) all the time (even if the app is not running)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589017/windows-phone-8-how-to-check-if-there-are-new-messages-on-the-database-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Background Services](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/11/23/leveraging-background-services-and-agents-in-windows-phone-7-mango.aspx) - That is what you need.

> Scheduled Tasks and background agents allow an application to execute
>   code in the background, even when the application is not running in
>   the foreground. The different types of Scheduled Tasks are designed
>   for different types of background processing scenarios and therefore
>   have different behaviors and constraints. This topic describes the
>   scheduling, duration, and limitations of scheduled tasks.

Also you need to check [SO question about WP Toast Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209535/toast-notification-when-app-is-not-running)

Hope its help.